# Owl Carousel alert when two slides match

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I have two carousels [see codpen link](http://codepen.io/makingsnippets/pen/XJXMvj/). Im trying to do something when two specific slides appear above each other something like:

```
  function match(){
  var topCarousel = $('#carousel-top').data('owlCarousel');
  var bottomCarousel = $('#carousel-bottom').data('owlCarousel');
  if(topCarousel.currentItem === 2 && bottomCarousel.currentItem === 2){alert('Match!')}}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbZLGb

use the `afterMove` event to get the current indexes for both the carousel and then call the function `match()`.

```
// the current value of the index for both the carousel
var currIndTop=0;
var currIndBottom=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#carousel-top').owlCarousel({
    singleItem : true,
    pagination : false,
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: [
      "<i class='icon left'></i>",
      "<i class='icon right'></i>"
      ],
    // an event that is triggered when the slide changes
    afterMove:function(i){
      // get top carousel
      var $car = $('#carousel-top').data('owlCarousel');
      // get current index for top carousel
      currIndTop = $car.currentItem;
      match();
    }
  });

  // similarly to the previous carousel
  $('#carousel-bottom').owlCarousel({
    singleItem : true,
    pagination : false,
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: [
      "<i class='icon left'></i>",
      "<i class='icon right'></i>"
      ],
    afterMove:function(i){
      var $car = $('#carousel-bottom').data('owlCarousel');
      currIndBottom = $car.currentItem;
      match();
    }
  });

  function match(){
      // this is unnecessary. I forgot to delete
      // var topCarousel = $('#carousel-top').data('owlCarousel');
      // var bottomCarousel = $('#carousel-bottom').data('owlCarousel');

      if(currIndBottom === 2 && currIndBottom === 2){alert('Match!')}
   }


  $(".header-top,.header-bottom")
    .velocity("transition.slideLeftIn", { stagger: 300 })
    .delay(750)

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this it is much appreciated. Would you have a moment to explain your solution in a little more detail? I'm not sure I understand how both carousels are being matched? Many thanks

Comment: Please see the comments in the source

Comment: Ok it makes a little more sense now that I know the commented out code is not necessary. This is down to my lack oj javascript / jquery knowledge but could you explain the first instance of 'match()' inside the 'afterMove:function(i)' and why the '(i)' Many thanks